# Format array as argument and console/write it

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm making a tool that takes csv table as input and outputs calendar events (ics). 
At some point I have a strategy that either outputs content of event to console, or writes data to ics file, so the method that writes output to a file looks like this:

```
def append_to_ics(event, day, file_name=None):
    output_file = open(file_name, 'a')
    output_file.write('BEGIN:VEVENT\n')
    output_file.write('DTSTART;TZID={}:{}T{}00\n'.format(event.TIME_ZONE, day.strftime('%Y%m%d'), event.start_time))
    output_file.write('DTEND;TZID={}:{}T{}00\n'.format(event.TIME_ZONE, day.strftime('%Y%m%d'), event.end_time))
    output_file.write('SUMMARY:{}\n'.format(event.class_title))
    output_file.write('DESCRIPTION: Teacher: {}; Type of class: {}\n'.format(event.teacher, event.class_type))
    output_file.write('LOCATION:{}\n'.format(event.location))
    output_file.write('TRANSP:OPAQUE\n')
    output_file.write('END:VEVENT\n\n')
    output_file.close()
```

'event' parameter is an object that has fields with time, title, teacher etc.
'day' is a datetime object, and 'file_name' obviously is a file I'm writing to. 
Method that outputs data just as a console log looks exactly the same, but there's no file open/close and instead of output_file() there's print().

**Question is:** I want to simplify methods so that I don't have to duplicate the same code for write and console outputs but I can't wrap my head around how to pass `array/tuple/?..` `'DTSTART;TZID={}:{}T{}00\n'...` then somehow format every field as earlier and then send it either to a file writer of console.

**What I already tried:**
First format an event as in method above and store everything in a table, and then just console/write everything in a `for loop`. But this looks like overcomplicating because I have to store a copy of event once again but as table and only then do something with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sys.stdout` that is a "file-like" object for the standard output (so, the console).

It's not `append_to_ics`'s job to care about how to open and close output streams, so you can put that out of the function.

Also, since you will have to loop over the outputs, we can also store the final string in a variable, for performance and readability.

This would look like the following:
import sys

```
def append_to_ics(event, day, outputs=None):
    outputs = outputs or []
    s = "\n".join([
        'BEGIN:VEVENT',
        'DTSTART;TZID={}:{}T{}00'.format(event.TIME_ZONE, day.strftime('%Y%m%d'), event.start_time),
        'DTEND;TZID={}:{}T{}00'.format(event.TIME_ZONE, day.strftime('%Y%m%d'), event.end_time),
        'SUMMARY:{}'.format(event.class_title),
        'DESCRIPTION: Teacher: {}; Type of class: {}'.format(event.teacher, event.class_type),
        'LOCATION:{}'.format(event.location),
        'TRANSP:OPAQUE',
        'END:VEVENT',
    ])

    for output in outputs:
        output.write(s)

# Call like this:
with open(file_name, 'a') as output_file:
    append_to_ics(event, day, [sys.stdout, output_file])
```

Note I'm using a context manager to properly handle the file's opening and closing.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot! Only thing I don't quite understand is that 'outputs', so if I pass 'sys.stdout' as argument to 'append_to_ics' and then call 'sys.stdout.write(s)' it'll console 's'?

Comment: `outputs` is a list of file-like objects. You don't have to use this argument, in which case the list will be empty (see second line) and nothing will be written anywhere. Or to do like your previous code, you can pass a list with a single item, like `[output_file]` (to write only in the file) or `[sys.stdout]` (to only print in the console). Or you can pass any number of file-like objects to write in multiple places, like in the above code.